# Visual Studio component import is null in vsix project (MEF)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mef, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension, and I need create my own `IWpfTextViewHost` (CodeEditor Window). This can be done via the `ITextEditorFactoryService` but this has to be loaded via the MEF framework.

But my import is always `null`, but I can't seem to work out why my import is `null`. I have a rought idea how MEF works, is there a method to call the `CompositionContainer`of Visual Studio itself? Or does the vsix project construct this container? If so, based on what settings?

```
public class MyViewHost {

   [Import]
   public ITextEditorFactoryService TextEditorFactory { get; set; }

   public IWpfTextViewHost CreateViewHost(ITextBuffer textBuffer) 
   {
      var textView = this.TextEditorFactory.CreateTextView(textBuffer);
      return this.TextEditorFactory.CreateTextViewHost(textView, true);
   }

}
```

**Edit**
this is the relevant part of the `extension.vsixmanifest`

```
  <Assets>
      <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="Build%CurrentProject%" Path="|dllName;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
      <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" Path="dllName" />
  </Assets>
```

Comment: What does your .vsixmanifest file look like?

Comment: Hello,
I added the relevant part of the extension.vsixmanifest to it. It has an asset as MefComponent

Comment: How do you get/create an instance of `MyViewHost`? This class does not implement any known interface and you are not exporting it as a MEF component. It seems like this is not retrieved via MEF component registry so there is no way that imports will be populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer based on @nejcs response and this [gist](https://gist.github.com/madskristensen/4d205244dd92c37c82e7).
I'll post the solution:

```
[Export(typeof(IMyViewHost))]
public class MyViewHost : IMyViewHost
{
    [Import]
    public ITextEditorFactoryService TextEditorFactory { get; set; }

    public IWpfTextViewHost CreateViewHost(ITextBuffer textBuffer)
    {
        var textView = this.TextEditorFactory.CreateTextView(textBuffer);
        return this.TextEditorFactory.CreateTextViewHost(textView, true);
    }
```

`IMyViewHost` is an interface with the `CreateViewHost` Method. The `SatisfyImportsOnce` must be called in the constructor of the extension command class and the `IMyViewHost` must be imported in this extension command class.

Comment: I think that Export'ing MyViewHost is not needed to resolve the ITextEditorFactoryService [Import]. I.e. , SatisfyImportsOnce( ) is what solves the issue. If you Export for other reasons, then do so of course, but I don't think that the Export is needed for the [Import] resolution. Please correct me if I'm wrong.